# ORA01017 - invalid username and password logon failed

Tags: oracle-12c, oracle-database

1) I installed Oracle 12c (64 bit windows)12.2.0.1.0
2) I installed sql developer and tried to connect to the database,
I realized I forgot user name and password. I dont even remember if I entered one , I tried all I can remember. Nut I continue to get status - failure ora01017 invalid username and password;logon failed.

I used SID as ORCL , authentication type default , & local host & role as default. 
Can someone please help me ?
I'm total new to Oracle. How can I check what username and password I created while installing oracle database?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just uninstall and start from scratch, making sure, you notate the information for the user?

Comment: Not sure about windows but Linux have sysdba group which allow a local user to connect to the database over the socket. 'sqlplus / as sysdba' when logged in as a user of sysdba group and environment variables are set.

Comment: i have no choice to do re-install and spend another hour on this.

Comment: @user8371676 [see last part](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b32010/authen.htm#i1006045)

Answer (score 0):

You can connect using the local user as sysdba and change the sys password.

[REF](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b32010/authen.htm#i1006045) the last article is relevant